# How to upload a Changelog in Jenkins as Release notes of Hockey app

Tags: jenkins, version-control, changelog, hockeyapp

I want to upload changelog as part of the Input Release Notes field. Is there an environment variable or something like that so that I can put it in as part of my inputted release note? Can you guys please suggest how we could do it.

[image]

Comment: Please make at least a minimal amount of effort before asking questions. Any search engine + HockeyApp + Jenkins will lead you to the HockeyApp plugin which does this.

Comment: Christopher my question is, how we can retrieve changelogs If u have an idea can you please suggest me.

Comment: I told you already. There's a Jenkins plugin. HockeyApp Jenkins Plugin: Upload to HockeyApp > Release Notes > Use [build] change log. If you need *different* changelog information, then you should mention that in your question (or search for the existing questions on Stack Overflow regarding that).

Comment: Can you please suggest me, how we could use build CHANGELOG in InputReleaseNotes of Hockey app plugin like ${BUILD_TAG},${BUILD_URL} as in the above attachment. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The HockeyApp Knowledge base has an article on how to do that with the `puck` tool that is part of the HockeyApp Mac application.

You can find out more about it here: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-upload-to-hockeyapp-from-mac-os-x#example

Comment: Kerni thanks for the info, but here I would like to retrieve changelog info from jenkins to one file/variable so that i could upload it to hockey app release notes

Comment: Please check that article again. The `puck` client has an option to read the changelog and send it as release notes automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kerni, I am trying to generate the build from jnekins itself, So If there is a way to retrieve changelog from jenkins I could directly configure that log into hockeyapp plugin of jenkins. Jenkins have a Hockey app plugin to upload these files, So I don't think we need to install Client application in Mac, Can you please suggest me if have any idea.

Comment: The jenkins plugin doesn't have such a feature and I am not aware of another plugin that provides such a feature. Sorry.

Comment: - [How to pass ${CHANGES} to downstream job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576251/how-to-pass-changes-to-downstream-job) 
- [Log changes in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631145/log-changes-in-jenkins)  
- [Get access to Build Changelog in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823826/get-access-to-build-changelog-in-jenkins)
   It doesn't seem to be that easy. I'm searching for quite some time now and it looks like there isn't an easy solution for this. But using the linked HA script and the `collect_notes_type=jenkins_aggregate` option might work.  
I'll try it.