# Retrieve a list of unchanged files compared to the last checkout

Tags: svn, jenkins, changelog

I found that there is a *changelog.xml* in path "Jenkins/home/jobs/***/builds/build number", when I use subversion to check out files, the *changelog.xml* only record messages of changed-file. The content of this xml is "
someone2016-06-02T07:28:27.791890Z/5.DevelopLibrary/somepath/some.javaTest".But the changelog.xml of a not-SCM job just contains"".

How can I find informations about files that not change compared to the last check-out operation? Or which function or plugin writes this xml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log changes in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631145/log-changes-in-jenkins)

Comment: I will try the methods in "Log changes in Jenkins ". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+log

> All SCM must be able to write and parse a change log in order to be able to show it per build. The change log file is most of the times a simple XML file. The SCM must implement the method createChangeLogParser that delegates the parsing of the change log file to the SCM which returns a ChangeLogSet derivate. It is the responsibility of the checkout method to write the XML file, which then is parsed after the checkout method returns. To be able to show the changes in a build, two jelly files are used.
>
> The change log is saved per build, and most of the times it is an XML file. The change log must be stored by the SCM in the checkout() method, the name of the file is supplied in the checkout() method.

So it is part of the SCM plugins.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But there is a changelog.xml in other jobs like "email-sending " which isn't a SCM job , and there is no SCM plugin in my Jenkins.

Comment: Please add that changelog.xml to your question.

Comment: The changelog.xml of "email sending " contents nothing but "<log/>

Comment: And the header of that xml file? Which namespaces are referenced?